# Html output of a stored procedure into a table or variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I have a stored procedure dbo.someprocedure which takes input as sql query and returns Html table format.

```
Exec someprocedure 'Select * from dbo.Table'
```

This html I would like to insert into a table or a variable so that I can perform few changes on the result html.

I tried using

```
Declare @variable varchar(max)
Exec @variable = someprocedure 'Select * from dbo.Table'
```

it is executing but returning 0 the variable is not assigned.

Thanks in advance, looking for your answer.

Comment: This is because the return from a stored procedure is ALWAYS an int. This is clearly stated in the documentation. If you want to return a value you need to use OUTPUT parameters. But your procedure is scary beyond belief. I can tell without even seeing your procedure code that this is vulnerable to sql injection. You need to rethink this considerably. You should create an inline table valued function instead. That way you don't pass in the query to run. You return your html as the result of running a query.

Comment: Something like `Exec someprocedure 'Select * from dbo.Table'` look **very** suspiciously open to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative procedure, which served my purpose.

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[spQueryToHtmlTable] 
(
  @query nvarchar(MAX), 
  @orderBy nvarchar(MAX) = NULL, 
  @html nvarchar(MAX) = NULL OUTPUT 
)
AS
BEGIN   
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF @orderBy IS NULL BEGIN
    SET @orderBy = ''  
  END

  SET @orderBy = REPLACE(@orderBy, '''', '''''');

  DECLARE @realQuery nvarchar(MAX) = '
    DECLARE @headerRow nvarchar(MAX);
    DECLARE @cols nvarchar(MAX);    

    SELECT * INTO #dynSql FROM (' + @query + ') sub;

    SELECT @cols = COALESCE(@cols + '', '''''''', '', '''') + ''['' + name + ''] AS ''''td''''''
    FROM tempdb.sys.columns 
    WHERE object_id = object_id(''tempdb..#dynSql'')
    ORDER BY column_id;

    SET @cols = ''SET @html = CAST(( SELECT '' + @cols + '' FROM #dynSql ' + @orderBy + ' FOR XML PATH(''''tr''''), ELEMENTS XSINIL) AS nvarchar(max))''    

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @cols, N''@html nvarchar(MAX) OUTPUT'', @html=@html OUTPUT

    SELECT @headerRow = COALESCE(@headerRow + '''', '''') + ''<th>'' + name + ''</th>'' 
    FROM tempdb.sys.columns 
    WHERE object_id = object_id(''tempdb..#dynSql'')
    ORDER BY column_id;

    SET @headerRow = ''<tr>'' + @headerRow + ''</tr>'';

    SET @html = ''<table border="1">'' + @headerRow + @html + ''</table>'';    
    ';

  EXEC sys.sp_executesql @realQuery, N'@html nvarchar(MAX) OUTPUT', @html=@html OUTPUT
END
GO

DECLARE @html nvarchar(MAX);
EXEC spQueryToHtmlTable @html = @html OUTPUT,  @query = N'SELECT * FROM sometable';
```

@html contains the html output so that u can perform your operations on the html reformatting

example:

```
select @htmlTable = Concat('<html>
<style>
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 50%;
}
td, th {
border: 1px solid #B8B8B8;
text-align: left;
padding: 8px;
}
thead {
color:white;
}
</style>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
   <th bgcolor="#B8B8B8">col1</th>
   <th bgcolor="#B8B8B8">col2</th> 
   <th bgcolor="#B8B8B8">col3</th>
</tr>',substring(@html,charindex('</tr>',@html,1)+5,len(@html)),'</body></html>')
```

thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

What @SeanLange said is right. If you want to use SQL stored procedure to convert SQL table into HTML, you must use `output` when you execute SQL stored procedure.

For example - my table:

[image]

Create stored procedure

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CustomTable2HTMLv4] 
    (@TSQL_QUERY NVARCHAR(4000),
     @OUTPUT     NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT,
     @TBL_STYLE  NVARCHAR(1024) = '',
     @ALIGNMENT  INT = 0)
AS
    -- @exec_str stores the dynamic SQL Query
    DECLARE @exec_str  NVARCHAR(MAX)
    -- @ParmDefinition stores the parameter definition for the dynamic SQL
    DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500)

    IF @ALIGNMENT = 0
    BEGIN
        -- We need to use dynamic SQL at this point so we can expand the input table name parameter
        SET @exec_str = N'DECLARE @exec_str  NVARCHAR(MAX)
                          DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500)
                          DECLARE @DEBUG INT
                          SET @DEBUG = 0 

                          IF @DEBUG=1 Print ''Table2HTML -Horizontal alignment''

                          -- Make a copy of the original table adding an indexing column. We need to add an index column to the table to facilitate sorting so we can maintain the
                          -- original table order as we iterate through adding HTML tags to the table columns.
                          -- New column called CustColHTML_ID (unlikely to be used by someone else!)
--

select CustColHTML_ID=0,* INTO #CustomTable2HTML FROM (' + @TSQL_QUERY + ') SUB
IF @DEBUG=1 PRINT ''Created temporary custom table''

--Now alter the table to add the auto-incrementing index. This will facilitate row finding
DECLARE @COUNTER INT
SET @COUNTER=0
UPDATE #CustomTable2HTML SET @COUNTER = CustColHTML_ID=@COUNTER+1
IF @DEBUG=1 PRINT ''Added counter column to custom table''

-- @HTMLROWS will store all the rows in HTML format
-- @ROW will store each HTML row as fields on each row are iterated through
-- using dynamic SQL and a cursor
-- @FIELDS will store the header row for the HTML Table

DECLARE @HTMLROWS NVARCHAR(MAX) DECLARE @FIELDS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @HTMLROWS='''' DECLARE @ROW NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- Create the first HTML row for the table (the table header). Ignore our indexing column!

SELECT @FIELDS=COALESCE(@FIELDS, '' '','''')+''<td>'' + name + ''</td>''
FROM tempdb.sys.Columns
WHERE object_id=object_id(''tempdb..#CustomTable2HTML'')
AND name not like ''CustColHTML_ID''
SET @FIELDS=@FIELDS + ''</tr>''
IF @DEBUG=1 PRINT ''table fields: '' + @FIELDS


-- @ColumnName stores the column name as found by the table cursor
-- @maxrows is a count of the rows in the table, and @rownum is for marking the
-- ''current'' row whilst processing

DECLARE @ColumnName  NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @maxrows INT
DECLARE @rownum INT


--Find row count of our temporary table
SELECT @maxrows=count(*) FROM  #CustomTable2HTML


--Create a cursor which will look through all the column names specified in the temporary table
--but exclude the index column we added (CustColHTML_ID)
DECLARE col CURSOR FOR
SELECT name FROM tempdb.sys.Columns
WHERE object_id=object_id(''tempdb..#CustomTable2HTML'')
AND name not like ''CustColHTML_ID''
ORDER BY column_id ASC

--For each row, generate dynamic SQL which requests the each column name in turn by
--iterating through a cursor
SET @rowNum=1
SET @ParmDefinition=N''@ROWOUT NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT,@rowNum_IN INT''

While @rowNum <= @maxrows
BEGIN
  SET @HTMLROWS=@HTMLROWS + ''<tr>''
  OPEN col
  FETCH NEXT FROM col INTO @ColumnName
  IF @DEBUG=1 Print ''@ColumnName: '' + @ColumnName
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN
      --Get nth row from table
      --SET @exec_str=''SELECT @ROWOUT=(select top 1 ['' + @ColumnName + ''] from (select top '' + cast(@rownum as varchar) + '' * from #CustomTable2HTML order by CustColHTML_ID ASC) xxx order by CustColHTML_ID DESC)''
      SET @exec_str=''SELECT @ROWOUT=(select ['' + @ColumnName + ''] from #CustomTable2HTML where CustColHTML_ID=@rowNum_IN)''
      IF @DEBUG=1 PRINT ''@exec_str: '' + @exec_str 
          EXEC      sp_executesql
                  @exec_str,
                  @ParmDefinition,
                  @ROWOUT=@ROW OUTPUT,
            @rowNum_IN=@rownum

      IF @DEBUG=1 SELECT @ROW as ''@Row''

      SET @HTMLROWS =@HTMLROWS +  ''<td>'' + IsNull(@ROW,'''') + ''</td>''
      FETCH NEXT FROM col INTO @ColumnName
    END
  CLOSE col
  SET @rowNum=@rowNum +1
  SET @HTMLROWS=@HTMLROWS + ''</tr>''
END

SET @OUTPUT=''''
IF @maxrows>0
SET @OUTPUT= ''<table ' + @TBL_STYLE + '>'' + @FIELDS + @HTMLROWS + ''</table>''

DEALLOCATE col
'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
--This is the SQL String for table columns to be aligned on
--the vertical. So we select a table column, and then iterate
--through all the rows for that column, this forming one row 
--of our html table.

SET @exec_str= N'
DECLARE @exec_str  NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @DEBUG INT
SET @DEBUG=0

IF @DEBUG=1 Print ''Table2HTML -Vertical alignment''

--Make a copy of the original table adding an indexing column.
--We need to add an index column to the table to facilitate sorting 
--so we can maintain the original table order as we iterate through
--adding HTML tags to the table fields.
--
--New column called CustColHTML_ID (unlikely to be used by someone
--else!)

select CustColHTML_ID=0,* INTO #CustomTable2HTML FROM (' + @TSQL_QUERY + ') SUB

IF @DEBUG=1 PRINT ''CustomTable2HTMLv2: Modfied temporary table''

--Now alter the table to add the auto-incrementing index. 
--This will facilitate row finding
DECLARE @COUNTER INT
SET @COUNTER=0
UPDATE #CustomTable2HTML SET @COUNTER = CustColHTML_ID=@COUNTER+1

-- @HTMLROWS will store all the rows in HTML format
-- @ROW will store each HTML row as fields on each row are iterated 
-- through using dynamic SQL and a cursor

DECLARE @HTMLROWS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ROW NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @HTMLROWS=''''


-- @ColumnName stores the column name as found by the table cursor
-- @maxrows is a count of the rows in the table

DECLARE @ColumnName  NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @maxrows INT

--Find row count of our temporary table
--This is used here purely to see if we have any data to output
SELECT @maxrows=count(*) FROM  #CustomTable2HTML

--Create a cursor which will iterate through all the column names
--in the temporary table (excepting the one we added above)

DECLARE col CURSOR FOR
SELECT name FROM tempdb.sys.Columns
WHERE object_id=object_id(''tempdb..#CustomTable2HTML'')
AND name not like ''CustColHTML_ID''
ORDER BY column_id ASC

--For each **HTML** row, we need to for each iterate through 
--each table column as the outer loop.
--Once the column name is identified, we use Coalesc to 
--combine all the column values into a single string.

SET @ParmDefinition=N''@COLOUT NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT''

OPEN col
FETCH NEXT FROM col INTO @ColumnName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
  BEGIN

   --Using current column name, grab all column values and 
   --combine into an HTML cell string using COALESCE
     SET @ROW=''''
     SET @exec_str='' SELECT @COLOUT=COALESCE(@COLOUT + ''''</td>'''','''''''') + ''''<td>'''' + Cast(IsNull(['' + @ColumnName + ''],'''''''') as nvarchar(max))  from  #CustomTable2HTML ''
     IF @DEBUG=1 PRINT ''@exec_str: '' + @exec_str
   EXEC      sp_executesql
             @exec_str,
             @ParmDefinition,
             @COLOUT=@ROW OUTPUT

   SET @HTMLROWS =@HTMLROWS +  ''<tr>'' + ''<td>'' + @ColumnName + ''</td>''  + @ROW + ''</tr>''
   IF @DEBUG=1 SELECT @ROW as ''Current Row''
   IF @DEBUG=1 SELECT @HTMLROWS as ''HTML so far..''

  FETCH NEXT FROM col INTO @ColumnName
  END
CLOSE col


SET @OUTPUT=''''
IF @maxrows>0
SET @OUTPUT= ''<table ' + @TBL_STYLE + '>'' + @HTMLROWS + ''</table>''

DEALLOCATE col
'
END



DECLARE @ParamDefinition nvarchar(max)
SET @ParamDefinition=N'@OUTPUT NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT'



--Execute Dynamic SQL. HTML table is stored in @OUTPUT 
--which is passed back up (as it's a parameter to this SP)
EXEC sp_executesql @exec_str,
@ParamDefinition,
@OUTPUT=@OUTPUT OUTPUT

RETURN 1
```

Execute stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @HTML1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @HTML2 NVARCHAR(MAX)


EXEC dbo.CustomTable2HTMLv4 'select * from StarWars',@HTML1 OUTPUT,'class="horizontal"',0
EXEC dbo.CustomTable2HTMLv4 'select * from StarWars',@HTML2 OUTPUT,'class="vertical"',1

SELECT @HTML1+@HTML2
```

[image]